# Replace "^" char

Tags: java, regex, string, character

I'm trying to replace the "^" character on a String using:

```
String text = text.replaceAll("^", "put this text");
```

If text as the following value:

```
"x^my string"
```

The resulting String is:

```
"put this textx^my string"
```

This only happens in case of the `^` character

Why is this?

Comment: Have you read the Javadoc?  Do you know what a regular expression is?

Comment: Sometimes is better to test the obvious...
Sorry lord all mighty

Comment: It's not like I remembered the details of the method either - I had to look it up, just like you could have.  It _is_ annoying to ask other people to read the doc for you when they might be answering questions that are a lot harder for the poster to answer for themselves.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the non-regex version [`String.replace()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead of `String.replaceAll()`:

```
text = text.replace("^", "put this text");
```

Comment: if you don't need the regex don't use the replaceAll

Answer (score 5):

`replaceAll` expects a regexp as a first parameter. You need to escape it:

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\^", "put this text");
```

As for the why, the `^` expreg matches empty strings at the beginning of the parsed string. Then, `replaceAll` replaces this empty string with `put this text`. Which, in effect, is similar as putting `put this text` at the beginning of your original string.

Answer (score 1):

`^` denotes the beginning of a line in a regular expression. You need to escape it:

```
String text = text.replaceAll("\\^", "put this text");
```

Answer (score 0):

`^` indicates the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

`^` is a regular expression character which matches the *start* of a string.  You need to escape it like:

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\^", "put this text");
```

Details are on the JavaDoc of [java.util.regex.Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 0):

The symbol ^ matches the beginning of a line. If you want to match the caracter ^ you have to escape it

```
String text = text.replaceAll("\^", "put this text");
```