# Finding current location

Tags: android

Am using network provider to get current location lat,long. The code works fine. But the problem is getting latitude as comma separated value(42,44291 instead of 42.44291). I can't show google map using comma separated lat,long. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Actually this question is really basic. Maybe you should start with plain Java first before you progress to Android Apps.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666947/replace-char

Comment: what about replacing comma by dot before showing Google Maps?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace the "," with a "." in Java.

```
String latitudeWithComma = "42,44291";
String latitudeWithDot = latitude.replace(",", ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "42,44291";
s = s.replaceAll(",",".");
```

[As already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043977/how-to-replace-comma-with-a-dot-using-java)

Comment: this ain't no string, dude

Comment: you see that this question has been answered... why do you post exactly the same 3 minutes after?

Comment: i was answering at that time and searching for the link

Comment: replaceAll is nonsense when you only expect one char to be replaced!

Comment: what is your problem man? having a bad day?? lol. walk it off.
this question was answered years ago anyway.

Comment: and how is that? i just answered again and provided a link to that

Comment: replaceAll is a waste!